# Can I save a JS object (with methods) in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have some objects that encode text formatting methods and css styles, and I'd like to save them in a MongoDB collection (using Mongoose). The objects are a more complicated version of this:

```
const myStyle = {
    book: {
        templates: ["/authors/. ", "/title/. ", "/date/. "],
        authors: {
            format: formatAuthors
        },
        title: {
            format: formatTitle,
            style: {fontStyle: "italic"}
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to send this this sort of thing to a server and save it in a MongoDB collection? According to the Mongoose documentation, Object is not a valid schemaType, so I can't just save it straightforwardly as a JS object.

Comment: Depends on your actual use case, but in most cases you want to store the methods at application level, so you could just store in database the method name for example, and then you call the method you want based on the name from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add methods through the Schema.methods field.

```
SchemaName.methods.methodName = function(){...}
```

Also take a look at this example [here](https://github.com/shu-csas-4118/event-tracker-good-team-1/blob/master/models/account.js) for basic mongoose usage.

Comment: I need to add methods on the front end, and then send the object to the server. Is that possible?

Comment: @Brian JSON doesn't have methods, so how are you going to serialise it? Also that generally doesn't seem like a good idea; what's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: That's not how it works, essentially you need to send the information as JSON via POST request (or sockets) to the backend, which in turn will store it in the Database. You could send the text of the function to the backend but as @jonrsharpe has pointed out, JSON doesn't actually support methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what serialize means. I have a MongoDB collection with documents containing a bunch of strings. On the front end, I feed the MongoDB document to a function that returns a React component formatted and styled according to myStyle. I now have 3 different styles (like myStyle) the user can choose from, and I'd like to make a form so the user can make her own style and save it to the DB for later use. So, for example, the user might choose a format from a dropdown menu, which would then populate myNewStyle.book.format with a pre-existing function. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is not a valid mongoose schema type but [**`Mixed`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) is.

> An "anything goes" SchemaType, its flexibility comes at a trade-off of
>   it being harder to maintain. Mixed is available either through
>   Schema.Types.Mixed or by passing an empty object literal.

You can read more about it using the above link.

In your case as long as the data you want to save is valid JS object you will be able to insert it.

Please note however that since it is a `schema-less type` there are some performance limitations when using Mixed as well as you need to call `.markModified(path)` when changed as again stated in the docs.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't save methods to mongodb